# Barchart style : hide items

Tags: highcharts, styles, bar-chart

I would like to finalize a barchart chart type. This was done with Highcharts.
I would like to know how to remove the small button at the top right allows among others to print the graph.
Also, how to remove the "Highcharts.com" link found below the graph?

Here is my PHP/HTML code :

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>

<div style="margin: 20px 0px 0px 60px">
  <!--
  The "oninput" attribute is automatically showing the value of the slider on load and whenever the user changes the value.
  Since we are using a category x-axis, the values are between 0 and 12. For this example, I'm adding your base year (2004) 
  to the output value so it shows a label that's meaningful to the user. To expand this example to more years, set your max value
  to the appropriate value and the base year to wherever you plan to start your chart's data.
  -->
  <script>
    $(function() {

    });

  </script>


  <div id="slider-range"></div>

    <p>
    <label for="amount">Year(s):</label>
    <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
  </p>

</div>
```

And here my JS code :

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
      zoomType: 'x'
    },
    colors: [
      '#d8d826'
    ],
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    title: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '0px'
      }
    },
    subtitle: {
      style: {
        fontSize: '0px'
      }
    },
    xAxis: {
      // NOTE: There is an interesting bug here where not all labels will be shown when the chart is redrawn.
      // I'm not certain why this is occuring, and I've tried different methods to no avail. I'll check with Highcharts.
      categories: ['1960', '1961', '1962', '1963', '1964', '1965', '1966', '1967', '1968', '1969', '1970', '1971', '1972', '1973', '1974', '1975', '1976', '1977', '1978', '1979', '1980', '1981', '1982', '1983', '1984', '1985', '1986', '1987', '1988', '1989', '1990', '1991', '1992', '1993', '1994', '1995', '1996', '1997', '1998', '1999', '2000', '2001', '2002', '2003', '2004', '2005', '2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012', '2013', '2014', '2015', '2016'],
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
      tickInterval: 1,
      minRange: 1 // set this to allow up to one year to be viewed
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 15,
      title: {
        text: 'Number',
        style: {
          fontSize: '0px'
        }
      }
    },
    tooltip: {
      shared: false,
      useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      column: {
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'data by year',
      data: [49.9, 83.6, 48.9, 69.1, 83.6, 40.9, 69.9, 83, 28.9, 40.9, 81.6, 24.9, 46.4, 49.9, 83.6, 48.9, 69.1, 83.6, 40.9, 69.9, 83, 28.9, 40.9, 81.6, 24.9, 46.4, 49.9, 83.6, 48.9, 69.1, 83.6, 40.9, 69.9, 83, 28.9, 40.9, 81.6, 24.9, 46.4, 49.9, 83.6, 48.9, 69.1, 83.6, 40.9, 69.9, 83, 28.9, 40.9, 81.6, 24.9, 46.4, 49.9, 83.6, 48.9, 69.1, 50]
    }]
  }, function(chart) {

    $("#slider-range").slider({
      range: true,
      min: 1960,
      max: 2016,
      values: [1960, 2016],
      slide: function(event, ui) {
        $("#amount").val(ui.values[0] + " - " + ui.values[1]);
        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(ui.values[0] - 1960, ui.values[1] - 1960)
      }
    });
    $("#amount").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0) +
      " - " + $("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));

  });

});
```

You can see the result on : https://jsfiddle.net/uvat8u05/26/

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
credits: { enabled: false }
```

removes highcharts link ([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#credits))
and

```
exporting: { enabled: false }
```

removes the menu
([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.enabled))

or use
    exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems 
to customize your buttons
([API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems),
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/exporting/buttons-contextbutton-menuitems/))

Comment: Note you have to have a license to remove the credits link.

Comment: the export menu will not appear if does not include the exporting module

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you.